# AWS SDK for .Net 5x slower than CLI getting file from S3

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, f#, mono

Using the AWS CLI I can download a 1 GiB file in around 10 seconds on my EC2 instance

```
time aws s3 cp s3://MYBUCKET/MYKEY .

real    0m10.355s
user    0m11.356s
sys     0m12.384s
```

Using the AWS SDK for .Net, the `Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility`, e.g.

```
use client = new AmazonS3Client()
use transfer = new TransferUtility(client)
transfer.Download(Path.GetTempFileName(), MYBUCKET, MYKEY)
```

with mono 4.2.4 takes

```
real    0m52.756s
user    0m53.992s 
sys     0m6.620s
```

How can I speed up the AWS SDK for .Net, so that it's comparable with the CLI?